# how to take the listview item from addTextChangedListener and display it in the corresponding edittext box

Tags: android, listview

```
//Listview adapter 

adapter_q = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Authors.this, R.layout.list_item_author,R.id.product_name, Quotes);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter_q);
        //textViewq=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.layout.list_item_author);
        System.out.println("before printing");

// filtering text

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Authors.this.adapter_q.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

            }


        });
```

taking the selected item from the list and seeting it to the edittext box

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg01, View arg11, int arg21, long arg31) {
                valc=   arg01.getItemAtPosition(arg21).toString();
                System.out.println(valc);
                inputSearch.setText(valc);

        }
        });
```

This is my search edittext box,i am getting values in it and it is filtering correctly, 
but my problem is that when i select a value from the list view, the listview still remains there,

how to dismiss it as i take value from that list view?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Quotes` is your arraylist of string that you passed into the adapter, you need to do the following:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg01, View arg11, int arg21, long arg31) {

                System.out.println(Quotes.get(arg21));
                inputSearch.setText(Quotes.get(arg21));

        }
        });
```

Because the data you want to display is stored in the array list instead.

Comment: Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type String[]
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable Quotes inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method

Comment: Its array so you need to do Quotes[arg21] instead of Quotes.get(arg21). And make sure that the Quotes is global variable.

Comment: The concept is you have an array of String for displaying in the list (in your case Quotes). When a list is clicked, you have index of clicked list (in your case arg21). Now all you have to do is get Quotes[arg21] (which is the text to display), and set it to the edit text. This is what I think.

Comment: my problem is that when i select a particular listview, the quote is ubtained in edittext, but the listview is still there. consider you are searching a country in a textbox, when you select textbox all the countries are listed, when typed 'i', all countries starting with i are shown, when n is typed it is filtered to countries starting with 'in'  and so on, when u select say india from it, the list should disappear and india should come in the textbox ri8? in my case india comes in textbox and also in alistview below the textbox

Comment: Are you saying that you are able to set text in the EditText, but the list should be hidden after setting text?

Comment: yes, that is it, when the required thing from list is clicked list should go

Comment: Well, then after setting text, you can simply set visibility of the list to GONE. And again back to visible in onTextChanged()